# MVVM Light is too fast :)

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, mvvm, command, mvvm-light

I have a simple WM7 Page with a `TextBox`. Futher, I assigned `EventToCommand` (a `RelayCommand<string>`) to this `TextBox`, reacting to the `TextChanged` event. For testing pourposes I made additional method `TextBox_TextChanged` in the page's code behind. Both the command and `TextBox_TextChanged` print a message box with the textbox content.

Initial value of the `TextBox` is `"ABC"`. Then I press D and:

1. `TextBox_TextChanged` prints `ABCD`.
2. The command prints `ABC`. D is missing.

Why is the command so fast?

Command declaration:

```
public RelayCommand<string> TextChanged {get; private set;}
```

Command initialization:

```
TextChanged = new RelayCommand<string>((s) => MessageBox.Show(s));
```

Command binding:

```
<TextBox x:Name="SearchTextBox" Margin="10,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding SearchString, Mode=TwoWay}" FontStyle="Italic" TextChanged="SearchTextBox_TextChanged" >
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="TextChanged">
            <GalaSoft_MvvmLight_Command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding TextChanged, Mode=OneWay}" CommandParameter="{Binding Text, ElementName=SearchTextBox}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</TextBox>
```

Comment: Can you post your code? It is difficult to know for sure without seeing how it is all hooked up together.

Comment: By WM7 do you mean Windows Phone 7?

Comment: add mvvm-light tag for galasoft mvvm-light support :)

Comment: @Sky - Yes, he wants to know why two delegates responding to the same event produce different results.  It appears that the command is running before the binding occurs when there is an event handler attached.

Comment: Just as an FYI, the TextBox.TextChanged event does not fire until A) the TextBox loses focus, or B) the Text is changed via Text property or an autocorrect event.   It could be that by having 2 listeners for the TextChanged event could have side effects that cause them to report different.

Answer (score 6):

I can't reproduce this behaviour. I have tried using EventToCommand and a Behaviour(which simply listens to TextChanged event).

Without seeing the code I suspect this might be to do with how you get the text of the search box or a logic error elsewhere.

This is a snippet of how I use EventToCommand:

```
<TextBox Name="SearchTextBox">
  <i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="TextChanged">
      <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding TestTextChangedCommand,Mode=OneWay}" CommandParameter="{Binding Path=Text, ElementName=SearchTextBox}"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
  <i:Interaction.Triggers>
</TextBox>
```

In the viewmodel

```
m_TestTextChangedCommand = new RelayCommand<string>(val => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(val));
```

As you can see I used a commandparameter to pass the value of the textbox to the viewmodel. This way the viewmodel doesn't have to know about the textbox to get the text value.

An alternative to this approach would be to use behaviours and TwoWay binding to update a property:

```
<TextBox Name="SearchTextBox" Text="{Binding TextInViewModel, Mode=TwoWay}" >
  <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <sc:UpdateOnTextChangedBehavior/>
  </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</TextBox>
```

UpdateOnTextChangedBehavior class:

```
    public class UpdateOnTextChangedBehavior : Behavior<TextBox>
    {
        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            base.OnAttached();

            this.AssociatedObject.TextChanged += 
                new TextChangedEventHandler(AssociatedObject_TextChanged);
        }

        void AssociatedObject_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(((TextBox)sender).Text);
            BindingExpression binding = 
                this.AssociatedObject.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);
            if (binding != null)
            {
                binding.UpdateSource();
            }
        }

        protected override void OnDetaching()
        {
            base.OnDetaching();

            this.AssociatedObject.TextChanged -= 
                new TextChangedEventHandler(AssociatedObject_TextChanged);
        }
    }
```

What the above does is mimick the behaviour of desktop WPF `Binding` with `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`, which is missing in Silverlight. So what will happen, whenever you type into the text box `TextInViewModel` property will get updated. This property doesn't haven to be a `DependencyProperty`, it could just be a normal CLR property.

Answer (score 1):

This works with TextBox via parameter for RelayCommand. IOW - `RelayCommand<TextBox>`

```
    <TextBox Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="8,136,0,0" Name="txtFilter" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="460" >
        <interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
            <interactivity:EventTrigger EventName="TextChanged">
                <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding SearchedTextChanged}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=txtFilter}" />
            </interactivity:EventTrigger>
        </interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
    </TextBox>

public RelayCommand<TextBox> SearchedTextChanged { get; set; }

SearchedTextChanged = new RelayCommand<TextBox>(OnSearchedTextChanged);

private void OnSearchedTextChanged(TextBox val)
    {
        if (val != null)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(val.Text);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and found that the databinding operation does not always fire until the TextBox loses focus. However, the Command will fire immediately.

If you want to guarantee that the databinding has occurred before you use the value, you can call the `BindingExpression.UpdateSource()` method on your control. Try something like this:

```csh
var bindTarget = SearchTextBox.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);
bindTarget.UpdateSource();
```

To avoid referring to your TextBox directly in your ViewModel (as you should with MVVM), you can use `FocusManager.GetFocusedElement()`. This is particularly useful when dealing with ApplicationBar buttons as they don't seem to receive focus when used.

Answer (score 0):

Some code I sued (similar to yours Command example):

Command declaration:

```
    public RelayCommand<string> TextChanged {get; private set;}
```

Command initialization:

```
TextChanged = new RelayCommand<string>((s) => MessageBox.Show(s));
```

Command binding:

```
<TextBox x:Name="SearchTextBox" Margin="10,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding SearchString, Mode=TwoWay}" FontStyle="Italic" TextChanged="SearchTextBox_TextChanged" >
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="TextChanged">
        <GalaSoft_MvvmLight_Command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding TextChanged, Mode=OneWay}" CommandParameter="{Binding Text, ElementName=SearchTextBox}"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

For some reasons messagebox shows a string with one character delay.

Comment: Welcome to stackOverflow! Note that you shouldn't post replies as answers here, either use comments or edit the original post, answers don't have any order.